# Why isn't a vertical stack view within a TableView cell dynamically generating height?

Tags: ios, swift

Here's a graphic explaining what I am trying to do and what I am seeing:

[image]

Getting the headline and supporting content into each cell works as expected, but I tried to use the following code within my UITableViewDataSource delegate to test to see blocks of color go into the vertical stack view but it is only showing a yellow line which leads me to believe that the height of the vertical stack view is not increasing at all.

**Where I think the problem is:** I set the constraints on the vertical stack view each to 0 hoping that the bottom 0 means it will continue down as far as necessary (i.e. it is 0 from the bottom, whatever the bottom may be) but perhaps this isn't the right way to do this and its actually constraining the height to 0.

```
    let box1 = UIView()
    box1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
    box1.backgroundColor = .yellow
    let box2 = UIView()
    box2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
    box2.backgroundColor = .yellow
    cell.verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(box1)
    cell.verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(box2)
```

Note: The stackview has a distribution of `fill equally` and a spacing of 4. Changing the distribution to `fill` removes the yellow line but doesn't solve.

I can't figure out where to add `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to the tableview row height, so maybe this is the fix?

Comment: Are you setting height constraints for the "yellow boxes"? If not, then your stack view has no way of determining how tall it should be.

Comment: I thought I was with the ```CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)``` but perhaps this isn't the same?

Comment: ok - a little confusing on your layout then... box1 background is red... is that your "red outline" in your image? box2 background is blue... where in your image is box2?

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right, that's really confusing. I'll update. The box1 and box2 should both be yellow boxes, I just put red and blue to differentiate for testing. The red outline in the image is the entire xib file which includes the headline, text, and empty vertical stack view (where I want to programmatically add in the yellow boxes).

Comment: It seems that there are a couple of potential culprits: First, do you have a constraint between the bottom of the `verticalStackView` and the bottom of the cell? And, if so, is that the only constraint that you’ve got to the bottom of the cell. Are you seeing any auto layout warnings in your console? Second, have you defined your cell to be auto-sizing (e.g. a `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` and a reasonable `estimatedRowHeight` value)?

Comment: @mpc75 - are you using a xib for your cell? or a Storyboard Prototype?

Comment: @DonMag and @Rob thanks for your help, I just figured it out. Rob, you're spot on, I failed to set up an ```estimatedRowHeight``` which, paired with removing the CGRects and setting the stackview to fill equally gives me enough to calculate everything I need perfectly.

Comment: New challenge for me is that it looks like cellForRowAt is running every single time I scroll so it's multiplying everything, but that is a separate issue :)

Comment: @mpc75 - you shouldn't really need an `estimatedRowHeight`... I just put you cell together without it, and no problems. But... add this func - https://pastebin.com/j8mMahKw - to your cell class to clear the added "boxes" when the cells are reused.

Comment: @DonMag perfect! removing from superview before adding worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments - it appears the OP solved the issue... but, here's an example which may help anyway.

This is the cell xib (the blue outline is the bounds of the stack view):

[image]

Stack view settings:

[image]

Note: to satisfy Interface Builder during design, I gave the stack view a height constraint of 100, but set it as a Placeholder so it is removed at runtime:

[image]

Result:

[image]

and after scrolling down a bit:

[image]

Here's the source for the xib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15705" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15706"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="261" id="qNz-cd-r4O" customClass="MPCCell" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="356" height="261"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="qNz-cd-r4O" id="rw4-5D-vJu">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="356" height="261"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iI3-m2-L2U">
                        <rect key="frame" x="36" y="12" width="284" height="45"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Headline" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UW8-L7-x4a">
                                <rect key="frame" x="108" y="12" width="68" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.26394423839999998" green="0.44803369050000003" blue="0.76730746029999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="UW8-L7-x4a" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="09x-rj-djb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="UW8-L7-x4a" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="iI3-m2-L2U" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Pjq-kb-VBD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="UW8-L7-x4a" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iI3-m2-L2U" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="sbt-LW-A1a"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="UW8-L7-x4a" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="iI3-m2-L2U" secondAttribute="centerX" id="tbW-Up-s9e"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Q2N-gq-ZWR">
                        <rect key="frame" x="36" y="65" width="284" height="44.5"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Supporting content" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hbx-b0-ZsJ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="12" width="268" height="20.5"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.26394423839999998" green="0.44803369050000003" blue="0.76730746029999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="hbx-b0-ZsJ" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" secondAttribute="centerX" id="KMe-cw-HFN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="hbx-b0-ZsJ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="NGw-fR-eJd"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="hbx-b0-ZsJ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="TLL-g6-Fjq"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="hbx-b0-ZsJ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="tyG-4i-x2s"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="hbx-b0-ZsJ" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" secondAttribute="centerY" id="yBl-K5-xKl"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="hbx-b0-ZsJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="zpZ-83-jqU"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1YZ-yV-ruW">
                        <rect key="frame" x="50" y="117.5" width="256" height="100"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="100" placeholder="YES" id="GVt-mR-ILU"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </stackView>
                </subviews>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="iI3-m2-L2U" secondAttribute="centerX" id="0X4-Z9-AJY"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="1YZ-yV-ruW" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Ba0-yG-ibk"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="iI3-m2-L2U" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="rw4-5D-vJu" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="Hcr-2X-7pH"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iI3-m2-L2U" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="RGZ-1L-32E"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="1YZ-yV-ruW" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.9" id="Rgu-ue-rwv"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="iI3-m2-L2U" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="rw4-5D-vJu" secondAttribute="leading" constant="36" id="SWp-gQ-CmT"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="1YZ-yV-ruW" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="eoV-nE-dBM"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="iI3-m2-L2U" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="36" id="jB2-qc-ba0"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="Q2N-gq-ZWR" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="iI3-m2-L2U" secondAttribute="width" id="mjX-lH-QBz"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="1YZ-yV-ruW" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="okC-Kj-vYa"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="headlineLabel" destination="UW8-L7-x4a" id="9mT-WA-Leg"/>
                <outlet property="supportLabel" destination="hbx-b0-ZsJ" id="buT-GP-BD7"/>
                <outlet property="vertStackView" destination="1YZ-yV-ruW" id="rSG-Ln-gzU"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="111.59420289855073" y="150.33482142857142"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```

and for the table view controller and cell classes to produce that result:

```
//
//  ExampleTableViewController.swift
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/13/20.
//

import UIKit

extension CGFloat {
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static func random() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red:   .random(),
            green: .random(),
            blue:  .random(),
            alpha: 1.0
        )
    }
}

struct MyCustomData {
    var headline: String = ""
    var support: String = ""
    var blockColors: [UIColor] = [UIColor]()
}

class MPCCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var headlineLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var supportLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var vertStackView: UIStackView!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // clear previously added subviews from the stack view
        vertStackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func addBlocks(_ colors: [UIColor]) -> Void {

        // for each colr
        colors.forEach {
            // create a view
            let v = UIView()
            // set its background
            v.backgroundColor = $0
            // give view a height constraint, but set its
            //  priority to 999 (prevents auto-layout warnings)
            let c = v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0)
            c.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
            c.isActive = true
            // add it to the stack view
            vertStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

    }

}

class ExampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myData: [MyCustomData] = [MyCustomData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // lets just create a sample data set
        // 15 rows, with varying number of random-color "blocks"
        // to add to the cell's stack view

        let numBlocks: [Int] = [2, 3, 2, 5, 4]

        for i in 0..<15 {
            var d = MyCustomData()
            d.headline = "Headline \(i + 1)"
            d.support = "Supporting content \(i + 1)"
            if i % 3 == 1 {
                d.support += " - every third row will have more text here, so we can demonstrate auto-height when word wrapping."
            }
            var colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor]()
            for _ in 0..<numBlocks[i % numBlocks.count] {
                colors.append(.random())
            }
            d.blockColors = colors
            myData.append(d)
        }

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "MPCCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MPCCell")

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MPCCell", for: indexPath) as! MPCCell

        let d = myData[indexPath.row]

        cell.headlineLabel.text = d.headline
        cell.supportLabel.text = d.support
        cell.addBlocks(d.blockColors)

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for auto resizing tableview cell height you must use autoconstrains

```
let box1 = UIView()
box1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
box1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
box1.backgroundColor = .yellow
let box2 = UIView()
box2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
box2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true

box2.backgroundColor = .yellow
cell.verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(box1)
cell.verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(box2)

cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```